# Postfix mysteriously stops running

Tags: linux, postfix, memory

My server has been experiencing this problem once every couple months:

1. Application becomes unavailable to users
2. Application log filled 100% disk space with an error message that it cannot connect to local socket to send email.
3. postfix is not running.
4. I don't see anything in the logs that indicates why postfix died.

My server is stock Ubuntu 12.04 + stable Python application that runs 24/7 + daily cron 
backups.

I do see this in dmesg, but am not sure if it's related (also not sure about the dates being December...):

```
[Sun Dec  1 02:13:10 2013] OOM killed process 561 (named) vm:87916kB, rss:92kB, swap:12680kB
[Sun Dec  1 02:13:10 2013] OOM killed process 229 (upstart-udev-br) vm:2784kB, rss:4kB, swap:172kB
[Sun Dec  1 02:13:10 2013] OOM killed process 337 (upstart-socket-) vm:2796kB, rss:148kB, swap:68kB
[Sun Dec  1 02:13:10 2013] OOM killed process 671 (master) vm:4528kB, rss:152kB, swap:148kB
[Sun Dec  1 02:13:10 2013] OOM killed process 679 (qmgr) vm:4688kB, rss:204kB, swap:180kB
```

It seems like master and qmgr are postfix processes....

```
root     16747     1  0 07:22 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/postfix/master
postfix  16748 16747  0 07:22 ?        00:00:00 pickup -l -t fifo -u -c
postfix  16749 16747  0 07:22 ?        00:00:00 qmgr -l -t fifo -u
```

I'm not too experienced with server administration so I could use some help determining what the problem is. Is this something memory (RAM) related? Admittedly, the Python application runs at very high memory consumption (95%+).

Answer (score 2):

Dmesg indicates that you're running out of memory, triggering the [OOM killer](http://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer).

Also what does date say? It looks like you need to configure [ntp](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/NTP.html). Having date and time set wrong may very well be what is causing you trouble.

Comment: Thanks... I will look into limiting my app's memory usage. "date" is correct: "Sun Oct 13 07:46:23 UTC 2013"

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Petter H in [his answer](https://serverfault.com/a/545656/218590), the OOM killer has kill `qmgr` process. Unfortunately the `qmgr` [is the heart of Postfix mail delivery](http://www.postfix.org/OVERVIEW.html#delivering). *When you kill the heart then you kill the person that owns it.*

Postfix maintain [qmgr process](http://www.postfix.org/qmgr.8.html) as persistent one. It shouldn't die unless the [master process](http://www.postfix.org/master.8.html) told it, perhaps for reloading configuration. If `qmgr` died without `master`, then postfix will lose it's heart. It can recover and then kill itself.